# Missing letter from encryption

Tags: python, encryption, dictionary

My encryption is almost working correctly but not quite:

```
d1={'H':'Z','E':'P','l':'O','O':'J'}

def encrypt(table,string):
    encrypted=""
    for k,v in table.iteritems():
        k=string[0:]
        encrypted+=v
    return encrypted

print encrypt(d1,"HELLO")
```

This returns "ZPOJ." It needs to return "ZPOOJ." How can I make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: "This returns "ZPOJ." It needs to return "ZPOJ." Am I missing something here? Your output and what you need are the same.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks, sorry about that.

Comment: no problem, you might get more help as well tagging the language this is written in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. You should loop on `string` rather than `table`. Make sure that all character using in the `string` are defined as keys in `table`. `l` is replaced with `L` in `d1`.

```
d1={'H':'Z','E':'P','L':'O','O':'J'}
def encrypt(table,string): 
    encrypted="" 
    for c in string:
        encrypted+=table[c]
    return encrypted

print encrypt(d1,"HELLO")
```

Comment: I got you, thank you. This code helped me understand much better what I'm doing and helps me write a lot of the code I have to write for this assignment. I appreciate your clear code and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit like homework so I'll try to only give hints…

Problems in your current code :

```
k=string[0:]
```

This gets the whole string every loop, where you probably only want one character from it.
In any cases, you are not using k inside the loop.

```
encrypted+=v
```

This is the only place where you add to the result, but you are taking the value directly from the dictionary values. You end up with a string containing all values of the dictionary, disregarding the plaintext you are encrypting.

You want to loop over the plaintext string and for each character, look up the corresponding value in the dictionary. Something like this:

```
for k in string:
    encrypted = encrypted + table[k]
```

Note that you have a lowercase L in your dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, thanks to all. It is homework, but the instructors are really slow to respond, and I know I'm close, and it's due Monday night (and there's a lot more to it)